# Why does Rin in blue exorcist have an eye bigger than the other when uncontrollable?

Tags: tropes, blue-exorcist

Why does Rin in blue exorcist have an eye bigger than the other when uncontrollable?

It also happens in Naruto, when he doesn't want to use his powers to fight Amaru when Amaru is possessed for example.

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Because his evil side is taking over and besides, in every anime when they're mad one of their eyes get smaller than the other [image: Image result for natsu getting mad]